# What's the best way for me to run SSIS on my Synology NAS?

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssis, synology

I enjoy working with SQL Server and SSIS at my current job, and wanted to play around with it and learn some of the features I don't really use much at work in my own home environment. I have a Synology NAS with 32GB RAM, and it comes with support of Docker and a whole bunch of virtualization software. I was able to spin up a container of MSSQL Server 2019 under a development license in no time.

The problem is that SSIS is not currently supported on Docker. I've seen a few work arounds online (https://andyleonard.blog/2019/04/ssis-docker-and-windows-containers-part-4-adding-an-ssis-catalog-attempt-2/), but nothing that seemed very clean. Looking through the documentation, I see that SSIS is supported on RedHat, but doesn't support having an SSIS Catalog database. My end goal would be to be able to create packages on my personal laptop, then deploy them to SQL Server to have them ran on a schedule using SQL Server Agent (another thing not supported in the container).

It looks like I can spin up a VM of CentOS (which is more or less RedHat), but would lose a lot of the features I really like with the Windows version of SSIS. I can deal with that, but I'm curious how I could publish packages from my computer, if they need to be on the Linux file system. Yet at the same time, if I'm going this route, should I not just use CentOS as my main database and scrap the container I created?

What options are available to me if I want to work with SSIS? More specifically, how can I get a working version of it on Synology?

Comment: If the objective is to learn SSIS, why try and shoehorn it into Docker or Linux? Docker is not the solution to every problem, it's a good solution to some problems.

Comment: Absolutely! I honestly don't care where SSIS is, as long as I can run it from my Synology. I'm just trying to see what some good options are. I suppose I could also spin up a Windows 10 VM, and install MSSQL Server with SSIS on there. I'm really just trying to figure out some of the better options for getting SSIS running on Synology, bet it Docker, a VM, or whatever else.

Comment: I'm googling Synology to try and understand what it is... I thought it was just a NAS (network attached storage), but is it more than that?

Comment: I have to say: I've been data engineering since before DTS. In a greenfield solution, I would _avoid_ using SSIS at all. It's not a cloud ETL tool, and even on-premises, it can be quite an ordeal to get it working, specifically around installing the client tool and getting it to work.

Comment: The device certainly seems to be aimed more at bulk file operations / storage, not more complex workloads such as SSIS. I would say: don't complicate life by trying to get SSIS (an old technology TBH) running on this device.... just install it on your home PC

Comment: What is your Synology model?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I'm using the DS1618+ https://www.amazon.com/Synology-Bay-NAS-DiskStation-Diskless/dp/B07CR8RZYY.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for your responses!!! Synology is a NAS, but also the software that runs on top of it. It has a TON of really cool features and runs on top of a linux OS.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, there are other solutions out there. But SSIS is something I am comfortable working with, and working on it at home would really compliment my job. Sure, I could use something else like Talend, but I feel like why reinvent the wheel and spend hours learning something new when I can use something I am already comfortable with? As for the workloads I'd be pushing through SSIS, they would be relatively small workloads. After all, it is in my home environment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there.

I'm setting up the same thing this week-end and I'm going to use [Virtual Machine Manager](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/packages/Virtualization) to spin up Windows10 instead of CentOS.

There is no problem, you don't need Windows license if you use [Windows Insider ISO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/isos) (there is also the Enterprise edition).

And like you I'm going to use [Docker on Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/packages/Docker) for MSSQL.

As you have a good 32Gb Synology I won't be afraid to allocate 16Gb to the Windows VM. (Give 12Gb or 8Gb if you think you are going to keep it up day and night).
The problems are the CPU core you have to allocate. I suppose you have a quadcore so give 1 or max 2 core to that VM.

This way you can develop the SSIS packages on your laptop and push them to the VM or Docker or install Visual Studio and SSIS on the VM and that would be your development ambient through RDC.

If you want to push one step forward you can also use your Synology to [setup AD to your home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQI33Z2Re3Y).

(I'm not going to do that)

One last thing: CPU cores and RAM are important but if you want to see your VM fly change HDD to SSD.

For the rest I wrote an article about how useless is to [change the thermal paste of your Synology](https://www.jeeja.biz/2021/01/04/apply-thermal-paste-on-synology-nas/).

Comment: Thanks for your response and the great info!!! I'm using my Synology for several things: backup for home devices, plex media server, and I'll be backing up my security cameras to it once I set up a server rack. As such, I'll probably just assign 8GB to the VM and 1 core. I don't expect the workload to be huge for SSIS, since all the data I'm passing to it will be in home data.

Comment: I did notice that you said you were gonna use Docker for MSSQL and VMM for Windows 10 to host SSIS. In that case, wouldn't it be better to just have both on the Windows 10 VM? Is there a benefit it separating the two? From what I understand, you are essentially going to have to install MSSQL anyways (like an internal express edition or something) when you install SSIS. Love to hear your thoughts on this!

Comment: Of course, you can install Visual Studio + SSIS and then MSSQL on the same VM. I just use Docker because I mainly work with DBs and I need several SQL instances

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Yeah, if you needed several instances, it would definitely make sense to use Docker. I need Docker to run some .NET Core applications on my Synology. I think I'll go with your advice and run MSSQL + SSIS on a Windows 10 VM, then create my packages in Visual Studio (on my laptop) to push over to the Catalog Database. I'll test it out today and accept your answer if successful. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Seems like everything is working fine. I only gave it 1 core, and then 8GB of memory. It was admittedly a little slow to set up, but I've had no issue since then. Granted, I'm only using SQL Server for a small database with just a few tables. In an office environment, this would probably not fly. For what I'm using it to do, I haven't noticed any delay for connecting to the server, creating tables, or running queries.